# Abstract Algebra - Binary Operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Determine whether the definition of * does give a binary operation on the set. If it is a binary operation, determine whether if is commutative and associative. On Z, define * by a*b=a^b

Comment: Describe some of your attempts at solving this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Some examples of an integer raised to another integer exponent include (*but are not limited to*) the following:

$$2^3, 3^2, 1^0, (-2)^4, 3^{(-2)}, 0^0, \dots$$

Also of interest are $3^{(3^3)}$ and $(3^3)^3$